# Does a Bangladeshi and Permanent Resident of Canada require a visa to transit through Amsterdam Airport?

Tags: transit-visas, ams, bangladeshi-citizens

My wife and son will travel to Dhaka, Bangladesh from Edmonton, Canada. They have eight hours layover in Amsterdam Airport. They are Bangladeshi passport holders but they are Permanent Residents in Canada.

Do they require transit visas for Amsterdam?